# Как присвоить classList только к одному айди, а не ко всем?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*При нажатии на жёлтую кнопку она смещается вниз, как и синяя, но мне необходимо, чтобы жёлтая оставалась на месте, а синяя смещалась. Никак не могу понять, почему classList присваивает .active ко всем айди (Если что-то не понятно или не хватает информации, то напишите, я добавлю)*

```js
function popi() {
  document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.content_toggles {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#pop .content_blocks {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 200px;
}

#menu.active {
    margin-top: 103px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <input type="button" class="content_toggles" onclick="popi()" \>
</div>
<div id="pop">
    <input type="button" class="content_blocks"\>
</div>
```

Comment: В приведенном коде, только у одного элемента есть ID, это элемент с ID `menu`, о каких других ID идет речь? Класс `active` добавляется на клик только к элементу `#menu`. Это в принципе видно как и в коде, так можно увидеть и через инспектор кода. А смещается, потому что элемент с ID `menu` есть оберткой для двух Ваших квадратов и когда добавляется класс `active`, то Вы смещаете эту обертку вместе с элементами которые внутри нее `#menu.active {margin-top: 103px;}`

Comment: Поправил, почему всё равно результат остаётся прежним?

Comment: Посмотрите через инспектор кода на расположение элементов. Элемент `#menu` занимает всю ширину и находится выше элемента `#pop`, когда прибавляется марджин, он двигает и нижний элемент соответственно.

Comment: Да, теперь понял почему. А как мне это исправить?

Comment: Переверстать) Я не совсем понимаю к чему там `position: absolute;` на `.content_toggles` и `#pop .content_blocks` и чего Вы этим пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: @Simon з-индекс менять.

Comment: Они у Вас друг друга и так не перекрывают, менять `z-index` чтобы что? Ну и для того чтобы он работал, не обязательно использовать абсолют, он может быть либо релетив, либо элемент может быть флекс элементом, например.